# Cannot access website while other tab is downloading a file (from same website)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm working on a .NET MVC project that runs on a small webserver, with limited resources. The site does, however, have some rather large files that it serves to users. And due to the limited amount of available RAM on the server, the standard `FileResult` return type of the action resulted in an `OutOfMemoryException`.

So I had to work around this issue, because upgrading the server was not an option. I came of with the following solution:

```
public partial class DownloadController : Controller
{
    // GET: Download
    public virtual ActionResult Index(string path)
    {

        try
        {
            fullPath = Server.MapPath($"~/downloadable_files/{path}");
            var fileName = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition("attachment") { FileName = fileName }.ToString());

            Response.TransmitFile(fullPath);

            Response.End();

            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

    }
}
```

This works fine. However, while a user is downloading a file, they cannot continue to browse the website within the same browser. It's like the action locks the connection to the server while the file is being downloaded. I havn't encountered this before, and I wonder if it could have anything to do with the way I'm serving the file? I feel like I missed out on some basic knowledge here.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably just the ASP.NET Session thread lock. Nothing you can do to fix that if I got it right.

Comment: I might be asking a stupid question here - but wouldn't I have to access a Session variable, in order to created a Session thread lock?

Comment: No, you have to have Sessions enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Long-running requests can cause unpredictable results and poor performance in your web application. The default timeout setting for a request is 110 seconds. If you are using session state with a long-running request, ASP.NET will release the lock on the Session object after 110 seconds. However, your application might be in the middle of an operation on the Session object when the lock is released, and the operation might not complete successfully. If a second request from the user is blocked while the first request is running, the second request might access the Session object in an inconsistent state.

If your application includes blocking (or synchronous) I/O operations, the application will be unresponsive.

To improve performance, use the asynchronous I/O operations in the .NET Framework. Also, use WebSockets or SignalR for connecting clients to the server. These features are designed to efficiently handle long-running requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#long-running-requests-110-seconds

Answer (score 1):

If this indeed session locking as some users are suggesting then you might be able to fix it by disabling session state on this controller. Given of course you are not using sessionState anywhere within this controller.

```
[ControllerSessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public partial class DownloadController : Controller
{
  // etc.
}
```